# Hamilton equations-Symplectic Euler method

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, hamilton-equations, eulers-method

We know that $\dot{q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}$ and $\dot{p} = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}$, and we also know the values $Q$ and $P$ respectively of $q$ and $p$ at a later time step $\Delta t$. How could we prove that the quantities
$$
\begin{align}
Q &= q + {\Delta}t\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q,p),\\
P &= p - {\Delta}t\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(q,p)
\end{align}
$$
are not symplectic, while
$$
\begin{align}
Q &= q - {\Delta}t\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q,p),\\
P &= p + {\Delta}t\frac{\partial H}{\partial Q}(Q,p) 
\end{align}
$$
are symplectic?

Clarification:
The sets of equations define different numerical integrators: in the first case (qi+1,pi+1) directly in terms of (qi,pi), and in the second case qi+1 in terms of (qi,pi), and pi+1 in terms of (qi+1,pi).

Comment: Is the sign change in the second set intentional, is there some time reversal involved?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes it is supposed to make the process symplectic and thus energy preserving. However, I am not sure How I could prove analytically that the first one is not symplectic while the second is. I mean i can see it computationally but was not able to find an analytical proof of this somewhere!

Comment: Not what I mean. You have switched signs in the second set of equations relative to the correct ones in the first set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [canonical transformations via generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_3_generating_function).

You might also directly compute the preservation of the symplectic form,
\begin{align}
\sum _i dP_i∧dQ_i  &=\sum_i \left(dp_i-Δt \sum_j[H_{q_iq_j}(Q,p)dQ_j+H_{q_ip_j}(Q,p)dp_j]\right)∧ dQ_i
\\
&=\sum_i dp_i ∧ dQ_i-Δt \sum_i\sum_j[H_{q_iq_j}(Q,p)dQ_j+H_{q_ip_j}(Q,p)dp_j]∧ dQ_i
\\
&=\sum_i dp_i ∧ dQ_i-Δt \sum_jdp_j∧ \sum_i  H_{q_ip_j}(Q,p) dQ_i
\\
&=\sum_i dp_i ∧ \left[dQ_i-Δt   \sum_j  H_{p_iq_j}(Q,p) dQ_j\right]
\\&=\sum_i dp_i ∧  dq_i
\end{align}
Due to the symmetric coefficient matrix $\sum_{i,j}\sum_i\sum_j H_{q_iq_j}(Q,p)dQ_j∧ dQ_i=0$ and the same for the $p$ coordinates.

Note that except for a separable Hamiltionian like $H(q,p)=T(p)+V(q)$, the first equation
$$
Q=q+ΔtH_p(Q,p)
$$
would be implicit.

---

For the Hamiltonian compare
\begin{align}
H(q,p)&=H(Q-ΔtH_p,p)=H-ΔtH_q·H_p+O(Δt^2)
\\
\text{ and }
H(Q,P)&=H(Q,p-ΔtH_q)=H-ΔtH_p·H_q+O(Δt^2),
\end{align}
the arguments on the right all $(Q,p)$, to see that it stays largely constant. One can modify this to $\tilde H=H+\tfrac12ΔtH_q·H_p$ where the Taylor expansion to one order higher gives
\begin{align}
\tilde H(q,p)&=\tilde H(Q-ΔtH_p,p)=H-\tfrac12ΔtH_q·H_p-\tfrac12H_{qp}[H_p,H_q]+O(Δt^3)
\\
\text{ and }
\tilde H(Q,P)&=\tilde H(Q,p-ΔtH_q)=H-\tfrac12ΔtH_p·H_q-\tfrac12H_{pq}[H_q,H_p]+O(Δt^3).
\end{align}
This means that this modified energy functional has a global error of $O(Δt^2)$, the global $O(Δt)$ first-order error will mainly manifest as a time dilation.

Comment: @Lehmann   I am not so profficient with mathematic notatio. Is the inverse triangle a dot product?. Also what you derived shows that the second set of equations is symplectic?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: The wedge is the symbol for the outer product, which is among others used to construct basis systems for differential forms. Yes, it shows the step is symplectic and thus volume preserving.

Comment: The notation in total is a bit off since the equations should be done correctly with the gradient $\nabla_q H=H_q^T$. Then for instance $H(q-Δt\nabla_pH,p)=H(Q,p)-ΔtH_q(Q,p)\nabla_p(Q,p)+...$ has a product of a row and a column vector, that can also be written as a dot product of two vectors of the same type (rows). The second derivative is often written as $u^Tf''(x)v$, but I prefer to use a notation that indicates the bilinear form $f''(x)[u,v]$

Comment: Thanks! One more questions could this also be proved by using the M*J*$\tilde{M} = J$  relations?